# Enhance bass in sound system

Tags: fedora, audio

I use a high quality headphone which capable of producing really great sound. On another computer and on various OS, it was able to produce some deep bass sound. I previously used my headphone on a Lenovo L540 (with Windows, and so Lenovo provide Windows drivers).

I recently changed for a new L540 and a fresh Fedora. The problem is that the sound is now a little bit more "flat" and lose its deep bass.

Even if I look on the Internet how to enhance sound on Linux, I only found how to use `alsamixer` to put the sound beyond 100%.

Do you have any idea on how to enhance sound quality on Linux ? I DO NOT want a music player with equalizer, as I would like to enhance sound for all my sound streams (Youtube, VLC, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pulseaudio-Equalizer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Equalizer). To install:`sudo dnf install pulseaudio-equalizer`.

Though it might be a bit unstable, it hasn't been much trouble for me.
The arch-wiki also suggests using [pulseeffects](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=pulseeffects), but I can't tell how much that will that help, as I haven't used it. You can also try that.